# Both Sided Slide menu in android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

This is not a duplicate of any questions asked before.
I want a double sided slide menu.
I [referred this library](https://github.com/jaylamont/AndroidFlyOutMenuDemo.)

I tried to edit this project and here are my corresponding files:
**Sample Activity.java**

```
package com.example.flyoutmenuexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.flyoutmenuexample.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    FlyOutContainer root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.activity_sample, null);
        this.setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void toggleLeftMenu(View v) {
        this.root.toggleLeftMenu();
    }

    public void toggleRightMenu(View v) {
        this.root.toggleRightMenu();
    }

}
```

**FlyOutContainer.java**

```
package com.example.flyoutmenuexample.view.viewgroup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class FlyOutContainer extends LinearLayout {

    Context ctx = getContext();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth(), height = display.getHeight();

    // References to groups contained in this view.
    private View leftMenu, rightMenu;
    private View content;

    // Layout Constants
    protected static final int menuMargin = 150;

    public enum MenuState {
        CLOSED, OPEN, CLOSING, OPENING
    };

    // Position information attributes
    protected int currentContentOffset = 0;
    protected MenuState menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;

    // Animation objects
    protected Scroller menuAnimationScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
            null);
    // new LinearInterpolator());
    // protected Scroller menuAnimationScroller = new
    // Scroller(this.getContext(),
    // new SmoothInterpolator());
    protected Runnable menuAnimationRunnable = new AnimationRunnable();
    protected Handler menuAnimationHandler = new Handler();

    // Animation constants
    private static final int menuAnimationDuration = 500;
    private static final int menuAnimationPollingInterval = 16;

    public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FlyOutContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        this.leftMenu = this.getChildAt(0);
        this.content = this.getChildAt(1);
        this.rightMenu = this.getChildAt(2);

        this.leftMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.rightMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        if (changed)
            this.calculateChildDimensions();

        this.leftMenu.layout(left, top, right - menuMargin, bottom);

        this.content.layout(left + this.currentContentOffset, top, right
                + this.currentContentOffset, bottom);
        this.rightMenu.layout(left +menuMargin, top, right, bottom);

    }

    public void toggleLeftMenu() {
        switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
        case CLOSED:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPENING;
            this.leftMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(0, 0,
                    this.getLeftMenuWidth(), 0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        case OPEN:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSING;
            this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(this.currentContentOffset,
                    0, -this.currentContentOffset, 0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }

        this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable,
                menuAnimationPollingInterval);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void toggleRightMenu() {
        switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
        case CLOSED:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPENING;
            this.rightMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(this.width, 0,
                    this.getRightMenuWidth(), 0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        case OPEN:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSING;
            this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(this.currentContentOffset,
                    0, this.currentContentOffset, 0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
        this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable,
                menuAnimationPollingInterval);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private int getRightMenuWidth() {
        return  this.rightMenu.getLayoutParams().width;
    }

    private int getLeftMenuWidth() {
        return this.leftMenu.getLayoutParams().width;
    }

    private void calculateChildDimensions() {
        this.content.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
        this.content.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth();

        this.leftMenu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth() - menuMargin;
        this.leftMenu.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();

        this.rightMenu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth() - menuMargin;
        this.rightMenu.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
    }

    private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isAnimationOngoing) {
        int scrollerOffset = this.menuAnimationScroller.getCurrX();

        this.content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerOffset
                - this.currentContentOffset);

        this.currentContentOffset = scrollerOffset;

        this.invalidate();

        if (isAnimationOngoing)
            this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable,
                    menuAnimationPollingInterval);
        else
            this.onMenuTransitionComplete();
    }

    private void onMenuTransitionComplete() {
        switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
        case OPENING:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPEN;
            break;
        case CLOSING:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;
            this.leftMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }

    protected class SmoothInterpolator implements Interpolator {

        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            return (float) Math.pow(t - 1, 5) + 1;
        }

    }

    protected class AnimationRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            FlyOutContainer.this
                    .adjustContentPosition(FlyOutContainer.this.menuAnimationScroller
                            .computeScrollOffset());
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_sample.xml**

```
    <com.example.flyoutmenuexample.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Left Drawer Starts -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleLeftMenu"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleLeftMenu"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleLeftMenu"
            android:text="Button 3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Left Drawer Ends -->


    <!-- Center Starts -->

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:lines="2"
            android:onClick="toggleLeftMenu"
            android:text="Toggle Left" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:lines="2"
            android:onClick="toggleRightMenu"
            android:text="Toggle Right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Center Ends -->


    <!-- Right Starts -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleRightMenu"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleRightMenu"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleRightMenu"
            android:text="Button 3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Right Ends -->

</com.example.flyoutmenuexample.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer>
```

*The logical problem that I am facing is that* **on clicking the right toggle button the slide menu from right comes out with no animation and it cover equal amount of screen like left slide menu does, but the background main content screen gets disappeared**

**I have given in depth detail about my problem, you can directly copy-paste these files and run the project for better understanding of my problem**

thanks
regards

Comment: Your library link is dead, so I can't see what you mean, but have you tried this [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) ? It will let you have a menu on the left and the right

Answer (score 0):

You can use jfeinstein's Library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu which allows you to have menu on both left and right side of the content.

Comment: It helps to summarize the helpful portions of the link in your answer, and why it answers the question.